# How can move to a particular section of the page from a click on tab in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, functional-programming, components, frontend

Here is my code. I tried like this way. `Image.tsx` is the component I want to show when the link of the tab will be clicked. So I made a separate functional component. Then this was called on `toobal.tsx` file with the `id="come"`. Please tell me how add work this out

On **Image.tsx**

```
export function Img() {
    return (
        <div id="come" className="athelas">
            <div className="vh-100 dt w-100 tc bg-dark-gray white cover"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${a8})` }}
            >
                <div className="dtc v-mid">
                    some text here
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And on **Toolbar.tsx**

```
<Link
     className="center h3 red"
     to='#come'
     style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
     /onClick={() => window.scrollTo(0, )}
>
     Upon onclick here, will goto the div
</Link>
```

What should I add?

Comment: Would be great if you provide a codesandbox with your question